# How to remove package installed as egg?

Tags: pip, python-3.4

My `pip3 list` shows this line:

`pulsar (3.4.0-beta.1, /home/dejan/work/myproject/src/pulsar)`

I can't find way to remove it. Normal pip3 uninstall does not work. Any ideas? The project I work on has requirements.txt file with the following line: `-e git+https://github.com/quantmind/pulsar.git#egg=pulsar` - I hope that helps find out why i can't uninstall it...

Here is what I tried:

`dejan@mypc:~$ pip3 uninstall pulsar
Can't uninstall 'pulsar'. No files were found to uninstall.`

Comment: Define *does not work* here. Do you get an error message? Please include the exact output you see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I've just updated the question with more information.

Comment: So is `/home/dejan/work/myproject/src/pulsar` empty?

Comment: Nope. It is still there, should I delete it?